# Get an Icon with subtext and then a list on the same line?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, reactjs, text-styling

I'm trying to simply make an icon with subtext and then menu options all on the same line.  However, it keeps positioning the menu options on a different line.
I.e., my html looks like the following: 
Icon(w/subtext)
**space
Test1 Test2 etc...

```css
    .wrapper {
      display: inline-block;
      white-space: nowrap;
    }
    
    ul li {
      display: inline;
      white-space: nowrap;
    }
```

```html
  <div>
    <div className="wrapper">
     <div className="logo">
   <a href="/"><img height="35" width="35" src={Logo} alt="TriLogo"/></a>
     </div>
     <div className="text">
      Triangular
     </div>
    </div>
    <ul>     
     <li><a href="/">Test1</a></li>
     <li><a href="/">Test2</a></li>
     <li><a href="/">Test3</a></li>
     <li><a href="/">Sit amet</a></li>    
    </ul>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did to make it work, hopefully this is what you needed.

I made the css look like this:

```
 li,.wrapper {
     float: left;
     top: 0px;
     margin-left:20px;
 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xJoeTheHobox/6ds37v8m/47/

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not displaying .wrapper's children (logo and text) inline. Same with the ul.

Below changes in CSS will help you to fix it.

```
.wrapper, .wrapper{
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

ul, li {
  display: inline;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```css
.wrapper, .wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align:top;
}

ul, li {
  display: inline;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="logo">
        <a href="/"><img height="35" width="35" src={Logo} alt="TriLogo"/></a>
                </div>
                <div class="text">
                    Triangular
                </div>
            </div>
            <ul>                    
                <li><a href="/">Test1</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">Test2</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">Test3</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">Sit amet</a></li>               
            </ul>
        </div>
```

You can also test it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/yq7kwx51/).

**UPDATE 1:**

I have move subtext to below the logo.

Test it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/yq7kwx51/2/)

Comment: It now puts Triangular to the side instead of as a subtext below the logo.